# Is it possible to conditionally hide properties at compile time in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, typedescriptor

Depending on a preprocessor directive, I want to set all properties in a class to EditorBrowsableAttribute.Never.

I thought about creating a custom attribute, derived from EditorBrowsableAttribute, but unfortunately that class is sealed.

I've had a look at ICustomTypeDescriptor, but in the GetProperties method, I can get hold of each property descriptor, but the attributes collection is readonly.

Any ideas?

Comment: There's not much point in this, just about every .NET programmer has Reflector.

Comment: Its not about totally protecting a class, I know thats not possible. I have a runtime version of an assembly, and the least I can do is partially hide the members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happened across this issue again recently and this time the answer came to me very quickly; simply set up a couple of constants:

```
Friend Class CompilerUtils

#If HideCode Then
    Public Const Browsable As EditorBrowsableState = EditorBrowsableState.Never 
    Public Const BrowsableAdvanced As EditorBrowsableState = EditorBrowsableState.Never 
#Else
    Public Const Browsable As EditorBrowsableState = EditorBrowsableState.Always
    Public Const BrowsableAdvanced As EditorBrowsableState = EditorBrowsableState.Advanced
#End If

End Class
```

Then in your code, decorate a member like so:

```
<EditorBrowsable(CompilerUtils.Browsable)> _
<EditorBrowsable(CompilerUtils.BrowsableAdvanced)> _
```

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to explicitly use the `#if` syntax

```
#if SOMECONDITION
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
#endif
public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

Comment: I know I can do that, but I'm trying to avoid doing it for every single member. It also looks messy, which is why it would have been nice to be able to create a class derived from EditorBrowsableAttribute, containing the #if statement. I'd then decorate each member with the custom attribute.